# Correct url for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, asp.net-core, controllers

could you please tell what is right url for the controller method  GetProfileById with attribute 'id' I tried many urls like 'http://localhost:5000/api/Profile/GetProfileById/1', 'http://localhost:5000/api/Profile/ProfileById/1','http://localhost:5000/api/ProfileById/1' but Postman shows message 'Cannot Get and my url'

Here is code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SocialNetwork.Repositories;
using SocialNetwork.Repositories.GenericRepository;

namespace SocialNetwork.Controllers
{
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProfileRepository repository;

        public ProfileController(IProfileRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = (ProfileRepository)repository;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Profile))]
        [ProducesResponseType(404)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Profile>> GetProfileById(int id)
        {
            var profile = await repository.GetById(id);
            if(profile != null)
            {
                return new OkObjectResult(Json(profile));
            }
            return NotFound();
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Would it not be `/api/profile/<ID>`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `/api/profile/<id>`. You can tell this by the `[Route("/api/[controller]")]` directive above the method. Then, any id's are added on after one more following slash.

So your full route with `localhost` (or your domain) would be http://localhost:5000/api/Profile/1

Comment: To add a bit more precision, the `Route` attribute combined with the `HttpGet` parameter makes up the URL. You could actually have `[HttpGet("{id}/json")]` and the URL would be `http://localhost:5000/api/Profile/1/json`.

Answer (score 0):

"[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)" and "[Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)" are good articles for this purpose.

In your case the correct URL is "http://localhost:5000/api/profile/1".

Note: If you still have problem with Postman, search for how to configure it.